# Sed command with many special characters

Tags: sed, special-characters

I am struggling with a sed command to replace a string with many special characters with another one with even more special characters.

I have 3 .sh files where I need to replace the following:

Text to replace:

```
SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= file.properties | tail -1 | awk 'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }'`
```

Replace with the following:

```
SERVER=`grep ^SERVER_UI= poller.properties | tail -1 | awk 'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }'`
echo "New SERVER_UI value is ${SERVER}"
if [ "$SERVER" == "" ]
then
    SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= poller.properties | tail -1 | awk 'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }'`
    echo "Old SERVER value is ${SERVER}"
fi
```

---

This is as far as I have been able to get by my own, but it's not working and I would appreciate some help:

```
sed -i.bak 's,SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= file.properties | tail -1 | awk \'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }\'`,SERVER=`grep ^SERVER_UI= file.properties | tail -1 | awk \'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }\'`\necho "New SERVER_UI value is ${SERVER}"\nif [ "$SERVER" == "" ]\nthen\n    SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= file.properties | tail -1 | awk \'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }\'`\n    echo "Old SERVER value is ${SERVER}"\nfi,' script.sh
```

If the help comes with some explanation too, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
sed -i.bak 's,SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= file.properties | tail -1 | awk '"'"'BEGIN { FS=\"=\"} 
{ print $2 }'"'"'`,SERVER=`grep ^SERVER_UI= file.properties | tail -1 | awk '"'"'BEGIN 
{ FS=\"=\"} { print $2 }\'"'"'`\necho \"New SERVER_UI value is ${SERVER}\"\nif [ \"
$SERVER\" == \"\" ]\nthen\n    SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= file.properties | tail -1 | awk 
'"'"'BEGIN { FS=\"=\"} { print $2 }'"'"'`\n    echo \"Old SERVER value is ${SERVER}\"
\nfi,' script.sh
```

I had to escape all the ***double quotes*** with **\"**

all the ***single quotes*** with **'"'"'** (singlequote doublequote singlequote doublequote singlequote)

and all the ***line feeds*** with **\n**

Comment: or just replace every "^SERVER=.*" with "SERVER=$replacement" ?

Comment: This sed operation is something that I will have to do multiple times against a script that is downloaded automatically, so I am not at liberty of modifying the original script before the execution of the sed command.

Comment: I meant, do a sed, but instead of looking for a complicated `SERVER=..........`, look for `SERVER=.*` ? (but beware as it could lead to replacing other lines... that's why I said "^SERVER=.*" instead if you know that this is at the very beginning of a line (and only once))

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have lots of commands chained together that you can easily do in single awk command. So instead of:

```
grep ^SERVER_UI= poller.properties | tail -1 | awk 'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }'
```

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F= '$1=="SERVER_UI"{val=$2} END{print val}' poller.properties
```

Now once that is settled you should create a new script file `subscript.sh` in your PATH with following commands (enhanced from your commands):

```
#!/bin/bash  
SERVER=$(awk -F= '$1=="SERVER_UI"{val=$2} END{print val}' poller.properties)
echo "New SERVER_UI value is ${SERVER}"
if [ "$SERVER" == "" ]
then
   SERVER=$(awk -F= '$1=="SERVER"{val=$2} END{print val}' poller.properties)
   echo "Old SERVER value is ${SERVER}"
fi
```

Finally run your sed command to replace old command with a new `subsscript.sh` call:

```
sed -i.bak 's#SERVER=`grep ^SERVER= file.properties | tail -1 | awk '"'"'BEGIN { FS="="} { print $2 }'"'"'`#subscript.sh#' script.sh
```

Comment: This sed operation is something that I will have to do multiple times against a script that is downloaded automatically, so I am not at liberty of modifying the original script before the execution of the sed command.

Comment: Yes that's fine not asking you to modify your script, that was just a suggestion. My suggested sed replacement command will work in either case.